# WebParts Uploading a file

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts

Does anyone know how to create a webpart with a browse button that allows me to choose an image file and display the picture on the browser, for instance to the image.

For instance this is the equivalent in Windows form under a button handler:

```
      Image img;
      OpenFileDialog openFileDia = new OpenFileDialog();
      if (openFileDia.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
          this.img              = Image.FromFile(openFileDia.FileName);
          pictureBox1.Image     = img;
      }
```

Thanks

Comment: where are you uploading, are we talking sharepoint webpart or an asp.net webpart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95954/Sharepoint-WebPart-for-Programmatically-Uploading